# Event touch up inside work in iphone but dont work in ipad ios6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uibutton, ios6

This generate the error

Generate a project for iphone only with orientation landscape left and landscape right
Add a button to the interface builder
Run on the ipad simulator
Press the button and it does not work.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem for orientations in ios 6

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in the ViewController does not help.

Kind of workaround would be to chose "Universal" (iPhone + iPad) as target device.